# How to get only clicked element by class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some elements with the same class name but I want to get only clicked element class and change it .

```
    var icon = $('.opener i'); // I want to take this class of only clicked element
```

Function

```
      $('.cate-inner span.opener').on("click", function(){
          var icon = $('.opener i');
        if ($(this).hasClass("plus")) {
          $(this).parent().find('.mega-sub-menu').slideDown();
          $(this).removeClass('plus');
            $(this).addClass('minus');
            icon.removeClass('fa-plus');
            icon.addClass('fa-minus')
        }
});
```

Comment: Please share some HTML code for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use context in query

`var icon = $('i', $(this));`

For better understanding you can check this [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context)

Answer (score 0):

Without html it's hard to tell but i will guess than replacing

```
var icon = $('.opener i');
```

by

```
var icon = $(this).find('i');
```

can do the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
"li").click(function() {
   var colorClass = this.className;
   console.lo
```

Try to do just like this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your Html where the icon located?

Basically, you can locate the icon with `$(this).closest( ".opener i" )`

```
$(this).closest('.parentElemnt').find('.opener i')
```

But to give you the exact code I need to see the HTML code.